# How to use BatteryStatsHelper to get app battery information?

Tags: java, android

When I use BatteryStatsHelper to get app battery infomation, I have set the permission "android.permission.BATTERY_STATS", but the system says I don't have the permission.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10164 does not have android.permission.BATTERY_STATS.
```

Comment: can you show your manifest file?

Comment: I find the permission may be only used by the system app . Is that true?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />

Comment: Check my edited version of my answer below.

Comment: Also for future note on stack some guys get really uptight on some thing so avoid posting updates and changed in you code as a answer, just edit the above question.

Comment: I think that BatteryStatHelper is no longer used and has been replaced by BatteryManager

Comment: you maybe check your manifest file and make sure your uid to be system

Answer (score 0):

Here try something like this and get rid of the Batstat methods.
Check [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200721185308/www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/getting-battery-information-on-android.html)
This should give you all the information you want for monitoring a battery.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    private TextView batteryTxt;
    private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
      int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
      batteryTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
    }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    batteryTxt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.batteryTxt);
    this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new   IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. The way you give cannot get the power comsumption of an app.  I want to know how to use the BatteryStatsHelper.class , espcially the refreshStats(),  because when I use this function, there will have a error that " uid 10202 does not have android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"      Thanks.